# how to change the data of the first observable using data from another observable including the condition in angular/rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I ran into a problematic one, let me provide the example schematically without any business details, so I'm fetching some data (*e.g. cars via getCars()*) from an API that returns an Observable. And I need to get the data from another endpoint by car model (*e.g. features via getFeatures(model)*) and then replace features data(we should do it for each car).

Addition to the question, how can we embed a conditional operator to make a request for getFeatures(...) only when (model === 'porsche')?

```
this.getCars().pipe(
 map(cars => {
 ...
}))
.subscribe(cars => {})

export interface Car {
   id: string,
   model: string,
   engine: string,
   details: Detail[]
}

export interface Detail {
   features: string[]
   ...
}
```

Could you tell me if you have any ideas? that will be very helpful.. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let cars$ = getCars();
let carsWithFeatures$ = cars$.pipe(
  map((cars) =>
    cars
      .filter((car) => car.model === 'porsche')
      .map((car) =>
        getFeatures(car.model).pipe(map((features) => ({ ...car, features })))
      )
  ),
  mergeMap((cars$) => forkJoin(cars$))
);
```

- use plain JS array filter to filter out all expect Porsche
- use plain JS array map to call the feature service for each remaining car in the list
- combine the features result with the matching car (I have simplified your model a bit)
- use `mergeMap` and `forkJoin` to combine the items back into a single (array) object for emission by `carsWithFeatures$`

Stackblitz(check console tab): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-drukvp

Comment: Nice, one small detail: `{ ...car, features }` does not match the `Car` object type. The `features` array is within the `details` array. I'm not sure what index the author wants to put the features though, or why both `details` and `features` are arrays.

Comment: Thanks, yes that structure looked a bit unusual and as you mentioned it is unclear how to populate it, so I simplified to avoid cluttering the answer.

Comment: One question: is there a difference between using `switchMap` and `mergeMap` in this case?

Comment: Good question - `switchMap` is useful if say another set of cars is emitted while still loading the previous cars features. It will cancel the previous requests and just load the new features. This is a more complex scenario than usual with the `forkjoin` and multiple requests - but I think it holds true as for the singular case.